# Unity: Game Object cannot move to right for the first time I press right arrow of keyboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, move, gameobject

**Update:** after go further with this book, I get the reason. It is the box colliders limitation of Unity it said in book. So I think we could close this ticket.

What said in the book:

"Right now, if you’re using box colliders on your tiles and on your player character, you might find that
you occasionally get stuck on things that you shouldn’t—your character may stop moving and press against
thin air. The problem normally occurs at the vertices between the closely positioned tiles, and unfortunately,
it seems that this is a slight issue with Unity itself rather than anything you can fix (apparently, it was
introduced in 4.3.1 and has yet to be resolved as of the time of writing).
If you do encounter this problem, just try using a polygon collider for Squarey himself, changing the
shape slightly by clicking Edit Collider, and then creating a small bump in the outline as in Figure 5-9 so that
you can “slide” over these imagined obstacles."

Following a book, I create a simple game using Unity 2D. It includes a `GameObject` named 'Player' which could do some simply action, move to left/right/jump when pressing <kbd>leftArrow</kbd>/<kbd>rightArrow</kbd>/<kbd>Space</kbd> key of my PC. And also some tiles as platform ground.

I found a problem that when the game is played, firstly the Player will drop on the platform then when I press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> Key, it has no effect. But if I press <kbd>Left</kbd> Key or <kbd>Space</kbd>, the Player will go left or jump then the <kbd>Right</kbd> Click will take effect...

This problem takes me for hours! 
Searching the internet but no answer found. One clue I found is that when I uncheck the `Freeze Rotation` option under `RigidBody2D`, then right move worked but I don't know why yet.

[image: Issue1_000]

[image: Issue1_001]

Here is my code, guys your help will be appreciated!

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int moveSpeed;
    public int jumppower;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius,
            whatIsGround);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumppower);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your player is not stuck in the ground collider.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the case is clear now because the limitation of box colliders. My bad not to do the further check...

Comment: @ChuckZHB: If the issue is solved, feel free to answer your own question and accept it. Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, let me close this question. The reason why the Player is occasionally stop during the moving is because the limitation of Box Collider.
The workaround could be using polygon collider instead and change the shapes, that is what is said on the book.

Of course I have a try on my project, it works actually. Thanks guys, the case is closed now and I will learn Unity step by step since the interest of games!